# in drupal8, dont want page refresh atfer comment submitting by comment form

Tags: drupal, comments

I dont want to redirect to a node after comment form submit. but it redirect me to some node-url/#comment-id.
I just want to stay on the same page/same node

Comment: research before asking a question

Answer (score 0):

[ajax comments](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_comments) module will give your the functionality you want.

Comment: Actually I m using default comment type .Is there any solution for it. I dont want to use ajax comment module .